# Does monero v12.2 work on a raspberry pi zero wireless?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Can monero v12.2 work on raspberry pi zero wireless and download the entire 50gb+ blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got 12.0 to work, but not running monerod, just the wallet.  Did test monerod, and it started syncing, but didn't want to wait 3 weeks, and didn't have the space.

Now I do have an Orange Pi Zero running monerod (12.0) pretty much fine  (it occasionally just quits)  But the OPi is an ARM7.

When I get a chance, I'll give 12.2 a go.